# Retrieving time from a time server from flash (as3)

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

Please do forgive a newbie to all this fancy Action script and flash in general.
Prior to any comments, I have been trawling for the answers for a good while now - with no luck so I figured I would poise the question at a few of the boffins on here.

So here it is.  What I am trying to accomplish is two simple analogue world clocks (which I had already done using Jquery) but IE has turned out to be the biggest nightmare to get this working correctly in - so I am trying a different avenue.

I have written a small script to retrieve server times which is below:

```
var ldr:URLLoader = new URLLoader()
ldr.load(new URLRequest("http://chronos.csr.net"))
ldr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded)
function onLoaded(evt:Event){
    trace(ldr.data)
}
```

Could someone tell me how I could print out the output from the above syntax to ensure it is   in fact working?  And seeing I pulled bits of the code from my various searches - is it a requirement to have the url pointing to a specific file?

If the above is by the grace of the almighty Pixel in fact working, how would one go about inputing it into the code below:

```
var now:Date;
var ct:Timer = new Timer(1000); 
ct.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTick);
ct.start();
function onTick(event:TimerEvent):void{
    now = new Date();
    var s:uint = now.getSeconds();
    var m:uint = now.getMinutes();
    var h:uint = now.getHours();
    second_hand_mc.rotation = 180 + (s * 6);
    minute_hand_mc.rotation = 180 + (m * 6);
    hour_hand_mc.rotation = 180 + (h * 30) + (m * 0.5);
}
```

And please do take into account DST as this was a slight pitfall I had even with JS (would have worked it out eventually but time is not on my side - excuse the pun).

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @wvxvw Cheers for the prompt response!  I require two clocks for one which will display the server time (which it is hosted on) the other is GMT (UK) - clearly I was heading completely down the wrong path

Answer (score 0):

There is an interesting thing you  might like to use, it's NTP (Network Time Protocol). It is a plain TCP stream which sends 4 bytes of data, which are the current time in the UTC format.

The problem in Flash is that you can't send plain TCP requests to an arbitrary server - Flash requires that the server sends a permissive policy response. So, you would have to proxy the responses obtained from NTP server (or, if you want to make it simpler, just print server's system date to the output stream) and call the script from Flash.

Here I found some example NTP synchronization script written in PHP http://www.xenocafe.com/tutorials/php/ntp_time_synchronization/index.php . You don't need the synchronization part, only the part where it tries to connect to couple of time servers and gets the response.

This won't be very precise, as connecting and sending data from Flash client to your server takes time, however, you can try to count the average time it takes for the data to travel to the client. Your course of action would be:

1. Send current date from your server script to Flash.
2. Once Flash receives the date, it sends it back.
3. Repeat setps 1 and two few times to collect enough data to calculate the average time it takes to travel. Let server times of sending the response be called `ST0`, `ST1`, ... `STN` and server times of receiving the response: `RT0`, `RT1`, ... `RTN`. Then the average time it takes to travel roughly `(RT0 - ST0 + RT1 - ST1 + ... RTN - STN) / (2 * N)`.
4. You would then record the delta and add it to the time sent to Flash every time it tries to synchronize with the server.

Again, all depends on how precise you want it to be. You could simply print date to the request output stream and ignore the time to travel / never synchronize your server against NTP server etc.

Comment: Very interesting indeed - I am not phased about how accurate the time keeping is, a query upon page refresh would be more than enough.  So I get how I can retrieve the time by placing the php script on my server and into flash.  How would I go about implementing the the retrieved server time into the onTick function?